# How do I restart my game without closing the program

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a mole shooter game. I want to be able to restart the game when you press the space bar. I have currently set it to `'a'` for testing purposes but that also doesn't seem to be working. I need help to restart my game without exiting the program.
I have added `///` to the area where I seem to be facing a problem. I also need a way to reset my score and counter.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
from threading import Timer

pygame.font.init()

win_width = 1000
win_height = 710

FPS = 90

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Mole Shooter")

white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

counter, text = 30, 'Time Left: 30'.rjust(3)

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score_text = 'Score: 0'.rjust(3)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('back_land.png'), (win_width, win_height))

aim = pygame.image.load("aim.png")
mole = pygame.image.load("mole.png")

moles = []
score_check = 0


def mole_spawn_easy():
    molex = random.randint(50, 950)
    moley = random.randint(450, 682)
    moles.append((molex, moley))


pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)


# pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
# mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(mole.png)


def paused():
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    # TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Your Score: " + score_check, largeText)
    # TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    # screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    final_score = ('Your Score: ' + str(score_check)).rjust(3)

    screen.blit(score.render(final_score, True, (0, 0, 0)), (((win_width / 2) - 100), (win_height / 2)))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # gameDisplay.fill(white)

        # button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        # button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def main():
    global FPS
    global screen
    global counter
    global text
    global font
    global score
    global score_text
    global run
    global background
    global aim
    global mole
    global moles
    global score_check
    global clock

    while run:
        ax, ay = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                counter -= 1
                text = ("Time Left: " + str(counter)).rjust(3)
                if counter > 0:
                    mole_spawn_easy()
                else:
                    # print("game over")
                    paused()
                    ///if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                            main()
                        counter = 30///

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                mx = mole.get_width()
                my = mole.get_height()
                for i in moles:
                    if ax in range(i[0], i[0] + int(mx)) and ay in range(i[1], i[1] + int(my)):
                        # print("hit")
                        score_check += 1
                        score_text = ("Score: " + str(score_check)).rjust(3)

        screen.blit(background, [0, 0])

        for pos in moles:
            screen.blit(mole, pos)
            # print(pos)
            if len(moles) >= 2:
                del (moles[0])

        screen.blit(aim, ((ax - 32), (ay - 32)))

        screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (32, 48))
        screen.blit(score.render(score_text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (800, 48))
        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indenting is incorrect in this section:

```
    if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
        counter -= 1
        text = ("Time Left: " + str(counter)).rjust(3)
        if counter > 0:
            mole_spawn_easy()
        else:
            # print("game over")
            paused()
            ///if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    main()
                counter = 30///
```

You have the if testing for the event.KEYDOWN inside the if that tested if the event was a USEREVENT, so it will never match. It needs to be like this:

```
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            counter -= 1
            text = ("Time Left: " + str(counter)).rjust(3)
            if counter > 0:
                mole_spawn_easy()
            else:
                # print("game over")
                paused()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                main()
            counter = 30
```

However, I should point out a different issue I see with your code structure. To restart the game you are calling main(), but you are doing that from inside main(), causing it to be recursive. You would be better off to do this in a non recursive way. perhaps move the run loop to a new method that main calls and then have the above exit from that and then main can recall it or something.

Comment: it still is not working however ill follow your suggestion to put my main code inside a function and not call it in a recursive way.

Comment: i was able to put my code inside a function and even set a restart button for starting the game again.

Answer (score -1):

Just break the run loop whenever you want, set the default values of your variables after that loop, and call to main again.

```
if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
    counter -= 1
    text = ("Time Left: " + str(counter)).rjust(3)
    if counter > 0:
        mole_spawn_easy()
    else:
        # print("game over")
        paused()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                break
```

After run loop:

```
# Prev code ....
    screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (32, 48))
    screen.blit(score.render(score_text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (800, 48))
    clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.flip()

reset_vars() // You have to implement this method or reset your variables here
main()
```